# C# WebBrowser - how to make a Download/DownloadComplete Event Handler

Tags: c#, html, xml, browser

I have a webbrowser object.
It is doing a lot of work so very often I run into a problem where objects are not loaded yet, or new request was not yet complete, etc.

So for now I'm using something like this:

```
Thread.Sleep(n);
while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
Application.DoEvents();
}
// do stuff here
```

But as already mentioned, I don't like it.  It is pretty unreliable. Plus the thread gets frozen.

I'm sure I've seen somewhere in internet something like DownloadCompleteHandler (not sure about the name), which was starting the process of downloading the page asynchronously, and after it is finished - I could call another handler to tell it what to do next.

But I can't find it again.
Would be great if someone can help.

Comment: I've just seen this comment and updated my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event.

The [Navigated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated.aspx) event is called when the page has been navigated to and has started loading, the [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event is called when the page has finished loading.

**Edit**

In response to your comment on your question; you're looking for the [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.progresschanged.aspx) event.

In fact it'd be easier if you just read through the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d67hf8a.aspx) documentation on MSDN. On this page there's a section for 'Events', which lists all of them and what they are used for.

Answer (score 0):

As well you can take a look at [WatiN](http://watin.org)

```
public class IEWaitForComplete : WaitForCompleteBase
```